# Monitor battery consumption which my ios app use

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, cllocationmanager, instruments

I have a GPS app and it runs constantly on background. I have took permissions from CLLocationManager of both background and foreground for iOS 8 and simply location enable service for iOS7. Now my app is constantly hitting a server at background. It has around 15 Web services. Is there a way to monitor how much energy consumption did it take as battery consumption is my prime issue. I found XCode Instrument tool to monitor it. But how to use it? I just want which process is consuming how much battery in the app. Is there a way to generate some kind of report in which we can see which process uses battery the most?